# What is the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^i}{\sqrt{A\alpha^{(i - 1)} + B}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What is the sum of the infinite series
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{2i}}{\sqrt{A\alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}},$$
where constants $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$. I know that this series does not converge for all values of $\alpha$. However, I checked that if $0 < \alpha < 1$, the series should be able to converge. Finding the sum of the series for this value of $\alpha$ seems hard though, and I have no idea how to approach it. Does anyone have a solution or some hints on how to do so?

Comment: I see no reason to think there is a closed-form expression for this sum.  (Unless $B=0$, where it is a geometric series.)

Answer (score 1):

To verify the convergence :

1. If $0 < \alpha < 1$ :
   $$\dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}} \sim \alpha^{2 i}$$
   and :
   $$\sum \alpha^{2 i}$$
   convergence then the series :
   $$\sum \dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}}$$
   converges.
2. If $1 < \alpha$ :
   $$\dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}} \sim \dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A} \alpha^{(i - 1)}} = \dfrac{\alpha^{i + 1}}{\sqrt{A}} \to +\infty \neq 0$$
   then the series :
   $$\sum \dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}}$$
   diverges.
3. If $\alpha = 1$ :
   $$\dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{A + B}} \not \to 0$$
   then the series :
   $$\sum \dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}}$$
   diverges.

we deduce that the series :
$$\sum \dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}}$$
if and only if $0 < \alpha < 1$.
In case of convergence, we calculate the sum numerically. For example we can take :
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}} \approx \sum_{i = 1}^{100} \dfrac{\alpha^{2 i}}{\sqrt{A \alpha^{2(i - 1)} + B}}$$